# MySQL Insert Into Having Issues

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure this out I can't believe it, I'm doing a simple insert, it's been awhile since I was at mysql but this is basic. Does anyone see any issue in here:

```
 'INSERT INTO social_handlers (name, desc, icon_dataurl, icon_imugr_url, icon_imgur_del, color, url_handler, admin_approved) VALUES ("test name", "test desc", "im data url", "img imgurl url", "del url", "color", "url", 0)'
```

There's nothing wrong with that is there?

Here's the table struct:

[image]

Comment: desc is a reserved word

Comment: *"There's nothing wrong with that is there?"* - Yes there is, [`desc`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Checking for errors would have signaled `...near 'desc`

Comment: Ohhhh my gooodness!!! Reserved words!! ughhh lol thanks all!!